# Ending HTTP Request in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

this my code for sending http request. Is there anything wrong why my request doesn't end?

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    req.write(uid);
    req.end();         //i think this line will end the requset, but not.
```

Thanks for the answer guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i missed to end the response with `res.end();`

```
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    req.write(uid);
    req.end();
    res.end();
```